# Crashes and hangs after memory DOWNgrade

Tags: imac, memory

I recently lost one of my SO-DIMM memory modules on my 20" iMac (2.4GHZ Core 2 Duo alu), and now my iMac is back on 2GB memory from 4GB. Both were ValueSelect (DDR2 667MHz 200-pin) modules from Corsair.

I'm having trouble with erratic crashes and beach balls from which it sometimes never recovers. Now, my question is, is there some sort of maintenance I can do to help my iMac after this downgrade?

I can tell it's struggling.

Comment: Do you have issues with crashes or do you just want to improve performance. If the latter, why not order some replacement RAM?

Comment: I have issues with crashes, I'm waiting for replacement RAM from vendor.

Comment: Same issue here, upgrading from 2 to 16 (4x4GB) VALUESELECT Corsair memory cards.
Did your replacement RAM worked?

Comment: Sorry, this is very late, but it was after all that, a harddrive waiting to fail. I replaced the harddrive with a lot of effort and it finally fixed all the crashing and hanging.

Comment: I started thinking of what was the cause for the harddrive failure, and my only conclusion was always sleeping the computer and never shutting down. Now the iMac never sleeps, never shuts down and is always on.